# Factory from generic Cache adapter with class pointer using FactoryBuilder

Tags: java, generics, caching, factory, ignite

I am trying to provide a generic `javax.cache` compliant adapter class to the `javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder` to retrieve a factory which is then used by `ignite` to instantiate a cache. The described problem may use Apache Ignite, however, I believe it's not necessarily related to Ignite but more to how generics and closures work in Java.

The Ignite `CacheStoreAdapter` interface is inherited from `javax.cache.CacheLoader` and `javax.cache.CacheWriter` and I am providing an adapter implementation. The implementation requires two (generic) types for cache key and value, as well as the value class reference to be able to instantiate the value in the adapter. See partial class for `MyCacheAdapter` below.

```
public class MyCacheAdapter<K,V extends StorableModel> extends CacheStoreAdapter<K,V> implements LifecycleAware {
    private final Class<V> valueClazz;
    public MyCacheAdapter(Class<V> valueClass) {
        this.valueClazz = valueClass;
    }
    @Override
    public V load(K key) throws CacheLoaderException {
        // load from database
        return valueClazz.newInstance(); // dummy instantiation
    }
    @Override
    public void write(Cache.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry) throws CacheWriterException {
        // write to database
    }
}
```

Now when I explicitly declare an adapter and provide it to the `FactoryBuilder` everything works fine...

```
public class MyPersonAdapter extends MyCacheAdapter<String,Person> {
    public MyPersonAdapter() {
        super(Person.class);
    }
}
```

... when cache is instantiated in my service starter.

```
// run init cache (on 1st node only)
public <K,V extends StorableModel> void init() {
    CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<K,V>();
    cacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(MyPersonAdapter.class));
    // add node filter to prevent other nodes from failing on cache distribution
    cacheConfiguration.setNodeFilter((node) -> { // exclude 2nd node });
    ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfiguration);
}
```

Working example so far! Now I don't want to explicitly declare `MyPersonAdapter` (and dozens more) but instead, let my starter take care of the adapter specifics based on provided type and key/value classes. So I can either provide my own factory...

```
public static class AdapterFactory<K,V extends StorableModel> implements Factory<CacheStore<? super K, ? super V>> {
    private final Class<V> valueClass;
    public AdapterFactory(Class<V> valueClass) {
        this.valueClass = valueClass;
    }
    @Override public CacheStore<? super K, ? super V> create() {
        return new MyCacheAdapter<K,V>(valueClass);
    }
}
```

... which is then used on cache initialization like this:

```
// run init cache (on 1st node only)
public <K,V extends StorableModel> void init(Class<V> valueClass) {
    CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<K,V>();
    cacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(new AdapterFactory<K,V>(valueClass));
    // add node filter to prevent other nodes from failing on cache distribution
    cacheConfiguration.setNodeFilter((node) -> { // exclude 2nd node });
    ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfiguration);
}
```

But this throws me `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` for the value class on my 2nd Ignite node since the class is not in the 2nd node's classpath. I definitely do not want to provide that class and I am asking myself what's the difference to the first implementation. I understand that the factory does create an instance when needed and to that time (as a cache is distributed to the other node) it has to know the value class which it doesn't. So I tried another implementation to get closer to the first (working) one. Instead of providing my own Factory I wanted to have my explicit adapter declared right before initialization as nested class:

```
public <K,V extends StorableModel> void init(Class<V> valueClass) {
    class DynamicAdapter extends MyCacheAdapter<K,V> {
        public DynamicAdapter() {
            super(valueClass);
        }
    }
    CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<K,V>();
    cacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(DynamicAdapter.class));
    // add node filter to prevent other nodes from failing on cache distribution
    cacheConfiguration.setNodeFilter((node) -> { // exclude 2nd node });
    ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfiguration);
}
```

This again throws me an `InstationException` since the class is out of scope for the factory I guess.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create an instance of DynamicAdapter
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: DynamicAdapter
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: DynamicAdapter.<init>()
```

So, I am wondering if there's a way to achieve my goal without a custom factory and class distribution across services (which is no option) but still having some dynamic adapter declaration.

**UPDATE**

Stacktrace for `InstantiationException` when class is returned by a static method

```
private static <X,Y extends StorableModel> Class getAdapterClass(Class<Y> valueClass) {
    class MyClass extends MongoIgniteCacheAdapter<X,Y> {
        MyClass() {
            super(valueClass);
        }
    }
    return MyClass.class;
}

// run init cache (on 1st node only)
public <K,V extends StorableModel> void init() {
    CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<K,V>();
    cacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(getAdapterClass(valueClass)));
    // add node filter to prevent other nodes from failing on cache distribution
    cacheConfiguration.setNodeFilter((node) -> { // exclude 2nd node });
    ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfiguration);
}

// output

class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to create an instance of IgniteServiceStarter$1MyClass
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7242)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:258)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:206)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:158)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:1812)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create an instance of IgniteServiceStarter$1MyClass
at javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder$ClassFactory.create(FactoryBuilder.java:134)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.createCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:1458)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1931)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1833)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.onCacheChangeRequest(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:379)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onCacheChangeRequest(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:688)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:529)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:1806)
... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: IgniteServiceStarter$1MyClass
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
at javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder$ClassFactory.create(FactoryBuilder.java:132)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: IgniteServiceStarter$1MyClass.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
... 10 more
```

Comment: You should post the stack trace of the `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a partial answer, but I think the second example (with the local class) fails because the local class is an inner class. Inner classes implicitly take an instance of the outer class as the 0th argument to the constructor, so they don't have a no-argument constructor.

```
class NewInstanceExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            staticMethod();
            new NewInstanceExample().instanceMethod();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            System.out.println("4. " + x);
            System.out.println("   caused by " + x.getCause());
        }
    }
    static void staticMethod() throws Exception {
        class StaticInner {}
        System.out.println("1. " + StaticInner.class.newInstance());
    }
    void instanceMethod() throws Exception {
        class InstanceInner {}
        System.out.println("2. " + java.util.Arrays.toString(InstanceInner.class.getDeclaredConstructors()));
        System.out.println("3. " + InstanceInner.class.newInstance());
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
1. mcve.NewInstanceExample$1StaticInner@7f31245a
2. [mcve.NewInstanceExample$1InstanceInner(mcve.NewInstanceExample)]
4. java.lang.InstantiationException: mcve.NewInstanceExample$1InstanceInner
   caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: mcve.NewInstanceExample$1InstanceInner.<init>()
```

Note the bold line, which shows that the constructor for `InstanceInner` takes an instance of `NewInstanceExample`, hence why [`Class.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) throws `InstantiationException`:

> `InstantiationException` - if this `Class` represents an abstract class, an interface, an array class, a primitive type, or `void`; or **if the class has no nullary constructor**; or if the instantiation fails for some other reason.

The solution would be to make sure the nested class has no enclosing instance, either by using the `static` modifier (as in your example which works) or otherwise declare the class in a `static` context (as in my example with the `static` method).

I don't think I can guess much about the `ClassNotFoundException` without more information.

Comment: Interesting point, I've now tried it with a static method. Unfortunately I'll have to return the class itself and not an instance to pass it to the factory.

Comment: See my update in the initial post for the full stack trace of `InstantiationException`. Be aware it's quiet Ignite specific.

Comment: Well, you can see in the full stack trace that it's still the same issue. `Class.newInstance` can't find the 0-argument constructor. All of the other stuff is just Ignite rethrowing that exception. You could try making the constructor `public`, but after testing a few things it seems like the local class just won't work here. Once you change the constructor to `public` you'll get an `IllegalAccessException` because the class itself isn't public, which didn't occur to me yesterday when writing the answer.

Comment: However, I don't know Ignite, so what the other answer is saying may be true. This just explains the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your first example works, it actually fails for me as well.

But in any case, the whole approach doesn't make sense. If you don't deploy classes, you will not be able to work with instances of these classes and your store will fail eventually anyway. For example, `load` method will fail on `newInstance()` call.

To avoid deploying classes you need to work with `BinaryObject`s in the store and set `CacheConfiguration#keepBinaryInStore` flag to true so that Ignite does not serialize/deserialize objects while invoking the `CacheStore`. Refer to this page for more details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller#binaryobject-and-cachestore

Comment: The point is that the cache is only used/instantiated on specific nodes (selected by a cache node filter) `cacheConfiguration.setNodeFilter((node) -> { ... });` That's why my first example works I guess. I know this information was not provided in the question. I do not want to distribute a service internal class to all nodes of my cluster since this would defeat the purpose of a service oriented approach where CI/CD are top priority.

Comment: I've also tried `keepBinaryOnStore(true)` but it doesn't make any difference. The nodes that do not work with the specified cache still asking for the class in classpath.

Comment: `keepBinaryInStore` will not change anything by itself, of course. You also need to change the implementation of the store so that it works with `BinaryObject` API instead of your classes. Once you remove all references to your classes from store and store factory implementations, you will solve the issue.

Comment: Regardless of node filter, configuration which includes the store is broadcasted across the nodes. This happens due to the fact that it is done by discovery protocol with organizes nodes as ring. You will have to either deploy classes on all nodes, or use binary objects as described above.